# Paypal payouts always return 403 error

Tags: php, symfony, paypal, paypal-rest-sdk

I have a web application that send payment to the user when they reach some level
That's the class that handle a single payment:

```
public function pagaSingoloAction(Request $request, $id_richiesta)
{
    $richiesta_pagamento = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository("AppBundle:RichiestaPagamento")->find($id_richiesta);
    if ($richiesta_pagamento)
    {
        $logger = $this->get('logger');
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $tassa = $this->get('application.settings')->ritornaImpostazioneDaNome("percentuale_tasse_pagamenti_richieste");
        if (!$tassa)
            $tassa = 0;

        $totale_richiesta_aggiornato = $richiesta_pagamento->getTotale();
        $totale_tassa_decurtata_network = 0;
        if ($tassa != 0)
        {
            $totale_tassa_decurtata_network = (($tassa / 100) * $totale_richiesta_aggiornato);
            $totale_richiesta_aggiornato = $totale_richiesta_aggiornato - $totale_tassa_decurtata_network;
        }

        $imp = new ImpostazioniApplicazione($this->getDoctrine());

        $apiContext = new ApiContext(new OAuthTokenCredential(
            $imp->getPaypalAppId(),
            $imp->getPaypalAppSecret()
        ));
        $apiContext->setConfig(array(
            'mode' => $this->getParameter('paypal_mode'),
            'log.LogEnabled' => true,
            'log.FileName' => 'PayPal.log',
            'log.LogLevel' => 'FINE'
        ));

        $logger->info("SETTATA CONFIGURAZIONE API CONTEXT");
        $payouts = new Payout();
        $sender_batch_header = new PayoutSenderBatchHeader();

        $sender_batch_header->setSenderBatchId(uniqid())
            ->setEmailSubject("New payment from request!");

        $sender_item = new PayoutItem();
        $sender_item->setRecipientType('EMAIL')
            ->setNote("Payment request n. " . $richiesta_pagamento->getId())
            ->setReceiver($richiesta_pagamento->getEmailPaypal())
            ->setSenderItemId(uniqid())
            ->setAmount(new Currency('{
                    "value" : "'. $totale_richiesta_aggiornato .'",
                    "currency" : "EUR"
            }'));

        $payouts->setSenderBatchHeader($sender_batch_header)
            ->addItem($sender_item);

        $output = "";
        try{
            $output = $payouts->createSynchronous($apiContext, null);
            $logger->error(var_export($output, true));
        }catch (Exception $ex){
            $logger->error($ex->getMessage());
        }


        $payout_item = $output->getItems()[0];


        if ($payout_item->getTransactionStatus() == "SUCCESS")
        {
            //ITS ALL OK

        }

        return $this->render('pagamento_singolo_richiesta/singolo_pagamento_dettagli.html.twig', array(
           'pagamento' => $pagamento_singolo,
        ));

    }
    else{
        return $this->render('pagamento_singolo_richiesta/pagamento_errore.html.twig');
    }
}
```

When i try to make payment:

```
try{
        $output = $payouts->createSynchronous($apiContext, null);
        $logger->error(var_export($output, true));
    }catch (Exception $ex){
        $logger->error($ex->getMessage());
    }
```

I always get 403 AUTORIZHATION but a month ago all works great!

So i can't understand what's the problem... I have checked with php sample code on paypal documentation and it's all ok like my code.

I use symfony framework in my application. 
I get payment without any problem but i can't send money.

I have also tried to upgrade all Bundles and symfony itself but nothink has changed, same problem.
That's the paypal error log:

[25-10-2016 11:21:08] PayPal\Core\PayPalHttpConnection : INFO: Response Status  : 403
[25-10-2016 11:21:08] PayPal\Core\PayPalHttpConnection : ERROR: Got Http response code 403 when accessing https://api.paypal.com/v1/payments/payouts?sync_mode=true. {"name":"AUTHORIZATION_ERROR","message":"Authorization error occurred","debug_id":"3676075eac96e","information_link":"https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/payments.payouts-batch/#errors"}

Answer (score 0):

The 403-response from PayPal API is always if there is something wrong with your credentials. Have you check if the desired PayPal-account is still active? And your client ID en secret ID are still legit?

Comment: thanks for reply.
Yes i have checked and it's all ok 
i still receive payment